# Samba low performance

Tags: debian, samba, slow-connection

I have a small professional network to manage: 1 server and 2 clients under Windows 7 pro.
On the 2 clients is installed a software that fetch datas from a proprietary database on the server through Windows network. Nothing very complicated.
It worked like a charm.
After some malware/virus issues, I decided to replace the windows server by a linux's one under Samba. OS is Debian 8.
It also works now, data are well retrieved but this is far more slow than with older windows machine.

I have read a lot of things on samba tuning and then tried several possibility to improve performance but nothing was concluding yet.
My first question: what is the best way to measure exactly performance of samba (network speed)?

Second question: does something seems obviously wrong in my smb.conf:

```
# Global Settings 

[global]

username map = /etc/samba/usermap.txt
workgroup = WORKGROUP
dns proxy = no
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
server role = standalone server
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user
usershare allow guests = yes


#socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=524288 SO_SNDBUF=524288 IPTOS_LOWDELAY
socket options = TCP_NODELAY 
strict allocate = Yes
allocation roundup size = 104857600

read raw = Yes
write raw = Yes
strict locking = No
min receivefile size = 16384
use sendfile = Yes
aio read size = 16384
aio write size = 16384

# Share Definitions 

[share]
comment = share
path = /home/share
guest ok = yes
browsable = yes
read only = no
writable = yes
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I have performed several test yesterday evening. Writing speed on the samba share comes from 7.5Mb/s up to 12Mb/s depending on samba conf tuning. I am pretty surprised it does not go faster...

Comment: 12MB or 12Mb? 12MB on a 100Mbit network is max, on a Gbit you can go way higher.
Test your network throughput first (iperf f.e)
then go with something without high overhead like f.e. ftp.
Test your underlying HW performance (IO/cpu)
Depending how large/small the files are you might have issues with CPU instead of Drivespeed.
Figure out the limits of the hardware itself, then measure each change until you are close enough to the max values you measured.